# TopoJson Install Error?

Tags: node.js, topojson

I am trying to install topojson with node.js and I am getting a frustrating error. I reinstalled the latest version of node.js (4.4.5) and running the standard install method. It seems like everything installs correctly. Then I try to do something with topojson and it is clear that not everything is installed correctly--illegal operation on directory. So it seems like it is installed but that I am having permission problems perhaps? Can anyone help with this?

```
C:\>npm install -g topojson
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\topojson-geojson -> C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson-geojson
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\topojson -> C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\topojson-merge -> C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson-merge
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\topojson-group -> C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson-group
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\topojson-svg -> C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson-svg
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm
└─┬ topojson@1.6.26
  ├── d3@3.5.17
  ├─┬ d3-geo-projection@0.2.16
  │ └─┬ brfs@1.4.3
  │   ├─┬ quote-stream@1.0.2
  │   │ ├── buffer-equal@0.0.1
  │   │ └── minimist@1.2.0
  │   ├── resolve@1.1.7
  │   ├─┬ static-module@1.3.1
  │   │ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.4.10
  │   │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │   │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14
  │   │ │ │ └── isarray@0.0.1
  │   │ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6
  │   │ ├─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2
  │   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14
  │   │ │   └── isarray@0.0.1
  │   │ ├─┬ escodegen@1.3.3
  │   │ │ ├── esprima@1.1.1
  │   │ │ ├── estraverse@1.5.1
  │   │ │ ├── esutils@1.0.0
  │   │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.1.43
  │   │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0
  │   │ ├─┬ falafel@1.2.0
  │   │ │ ├── acorn@1.2.2
  │   │ │ ├── foreach@2.0.5
  │   │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │   │ │ └── object-keys@1.0.9
  │   │ ├─┬ has@1.0.1
  │   │ │ └── function-bind@1.1.0
  │   │ ├── object-inspect@0.4.0
  │   │ ├─┬ quote-stream@0.0.0
  │   │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
  │   │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.34
  │   │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
  │   │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │   │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │   │ ├── shallow-copy@0.0.1
  │   │ ├─┬ static-eval@0.2.4
  │   │ │ └─┬ escodegen@0.0.28
  │   │ │   ├── esprima@1.0.4
  │   │ │   └── estraverse@1.3.2
  │   │ └─┬ through2@0.4.2
  │   │   └─┬ xtend@2.1.2
  │   │     └── object-keys@0.4.0
  │   └─┬ through2@2.0.1
  │     ├─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6
  │     │ ├── isarray@1.0.0
  │     │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
  │     │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
  │     └── xtend@4.0.1
  ├── d3-queue@2.0.3
  ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
  │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
  ├── rw@1.3.2
  └─┬ shapefile@0.3.1
    ├── d3-queue@1.2.3
    └── iconv-lite@0.2.11

C:\>topojson -v
C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson:259
  if (error) throw error;
             ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:603:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\rw\lib\rw\read-file-sync.js:14:28)
    at Object.readFileSync (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\rw\lib\rw\dash.js:7:19)
    at inputJson (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson:245:30)
    at start (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\d3-queue\build\d3-queue.js:68:13)
    at poke (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\d3-queue\build\d3-queue.js:56:26)
    at Queue.queue.defer (C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\node_modules\d3-queue\build\d3-queue.js:34:7)
    at C:\Users\Seth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\topojson\bin\topojson:196:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
```